# Linq how to write a JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Linq to EF, I'm using asp.net 4, EF 4 and C#.

Here are two ways I came up with to query my data. Ways A and C are working fine. B however needs to implement and additional WHERE statement (as "where c.ModeContent == "NA").

My question is:

- Regarding this kind of join (outer join, I suppose) what is the best approach in term of performance?
- Could you show me some code to implement additional WHERE statement in B?
- Any way to improve this code?

Thanks for your time! :-)

```
// A               
var queryContents = from c in context.CmsContents
    where c.ModeContent == "NA" &&
    !(from o in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes select o.ContentId)
    .Contains(c.ContentId)
    select c;

// B - I need to implent where c.ModeContent == "NA"
var result01 = from c in context.CmsContents
    join d in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes on c.ContentId equals d.ContentId into g
    where !g.Any()
    select c;

// C
var result02 = context.CmsContents.Where(x => x.ModeContent == "NA").Where(item1 => context.CmsContentsAssignedToes.All(item2 => item1.ContentId != item2.ContentId));
```

Comment: my eyes are bleeding for typos!

Comment: sorry English it is not my first language :-)

Comment: i revised some my question now should have less typos :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding query B you can apply the condition like this:

```
var result01 = from c in context.CmsContents where c.ModeContent == "NA"
join d in context.CmsContentsAssignedToes on c.ContentId equals d.ContentId into g
where !g.Any()
select c;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query will be **far** more readable and maintainable (and perform at least as well) if you [use your association properties instead of `join`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/):

```
var result = from c in context.CmsContents
             where c.ModeContent == "NA"
                && !c.AssignedToes.Any()
             select c;
```

I'm guessing that the navigation on `CmsContent` to `CmsContentsAssignedToes` is called `AssignedToes`. Change the name in my query if it's actually called something else.

This query can be read out loud and you know *exactly* what it means. The `join` versions you have to think about.